# Method not found error with different .class file

Tags: java, methods

I keep getting NoSuchMethodError for printArray()
My professor is requiring us to use his own .class file to check if we called our methods correctly but when I compile it not using his .class file I do not get an error message

```
public class ArrayOperations
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    

        System.out.print("Enter the data file name: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();    

        int[] array = new int[1000];
        int index = 0;
        int indexCounter = 0;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        while (input.hasNext() && index < array.length)
        {
            array[index] = input.nextInt();
            index++;
            indexCounter++;
        }

        input.close();

        int[] finalArray = new int[indexCounter];

        for (int i = 0; i < indexCounter; i++){
            finalArray[i] = array[i];

        printArray(finalArray, n);
      }


    public static void printArray(int[] arrayList, int n)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
        {
            for (int value = 0; value < n; value++)
            {
                System.out.println(value + " ");
            }

            for (int value : arrayList){
                System.out.print(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also post the whole stacktrace of error ?

Comment: @ShaikhMohammedShariq 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : ArrarOperations.printArray at ArrayOperationstTest.main(ArrayOperationsTest.java:30)'

Comment: The professors .class file is called ArrayOperationsTest.class thats why its different

Comment: can you post what is on the line 30 ? and also the test class. tnx

Comment: @JoshTell why you put you printArray(finalArray,n); inside your loop ? please change it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define `printArray` method within main method and hence ocmpiler is complaining.

Also you haven't declared variable n which you are trying to call method with. So use the call as:

```
printArray(finalArray, finalArray.length);
}//close main method
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `printArray` method located inside `main method` move it out side

```
public class ArrayOperations
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{    

System.out.print("Enter the data file name: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();    

int[] array = new int[1000];
int index = 0;
int indexCounter = 0;
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

while (input.hasNext() && index < array.length)
{
    array[index] = input.nextInt();
    index++;
    indexCounter++;
}

input.close();

int[] finalArray = new int[indexCounter];
for (int i = 0; i < indexCounter; i++)
{
    finalArray[i] = array[i];
}

printArray(finalArray, n);

}

//put it outside

public static void printArray(int[] arrayList, int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
for (int value = 0; value < n; value++) 
    System.out.println(value + " ");
for (int value : arrayList)
    System.out.print(value);
}
}
```

**`Also`** `n` is not defined in your main method

Comment: it is on the outside sorry I must've copied and pasted wrong ill double check it now